# is there a way to specify a constructor for a groovy script?

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy script called `Foo.groovy`, an instance of that script can be constructed using the following syntax:

```
def foo = new Foo()
```

i know if `Foo.groovy` looks like:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def bar

def someMethod() {
  //...
}
```

the following syntax:

```
def foo = new Foo(bar: 'baz')
```

will use some default constructor and actually set the `bar` field to `baz`,
but let's say that i wanted to manipulate the passed value of `bar` to add an 
exclamation point at the end like so `"${bar}!"`

would like to be able to do something like the following (which doesn't work AFAIK):

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def bar

Foo(args) {
  bar = "${args.bar}!"
}

def someMethod() {
  //...
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to accomplish that in groovy?

Comment: Typically you would not explicitly construct and bootstrap a Groovy Script. Usually you would run it using groovy command (or equivalent in IDE) and pass binding arguments on the command line.

Comment: thanks @emilles, this is in the context of a jenkins shared library where i have a series of scripts and i am calling `new` on them. i kno a little odd, but the jenkins environment is a little odd :)

Comment: I think there is an import/include method to make a sub-script available within another.

Comment: Otherwise, a script is a subclass of groovy.lang.Script unless you specify otherwise. And you can construct an instance with default constructor and call setBinding to pass context for free variables and call run() to execute.

Comment: Looking at the AST, it looks like you also get a constructor that accepts Binding. And you get a static main method.  So you should be able to call "Foo.main(args)" and the args from one script's bindings should be transferred to another.

Comment: appreciate you thinking about this @emilles, i added a little more example code in the question to hopefully provide more clarity to the ask. i've never used bindings directly, an example would be great if u have the time. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use setter method

(Foo.groovy):

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def bar

void setBar(def bar){
    this.bar = "${bar}!"
    println "Setter is executed. ${bar} -> ${this.bar}"
}
```

And if the calling party will look like

```
import Foo
def foo = new Foo(bar: 'baz')
println foo.bar
```

the following result appears:

```
Setter is executed. baz -> baz!
baz!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a method like `initialise` that acts as a constructor. That way you can use it for multiple arguments as well.

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def bar

// initialise can be used in-place of constructor for enclosing class
def initialise(args) {
  bar = "${args.bar}!"
  this // return initialised object
}

def someMethod() {
  println(bar)
}
```

This can be called as follows

```
def foo = new Foo().initialise(args)

foo.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Any free variable in the main body of the script can be satisfied out of the Binding object.  It works pretty much like a map because it has a map-based constructor and has overloaded getProperty and setProperty.  http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Binding.html

Main script:

```
def binding = new Binding(bar: 'baz')
def foo = new Foo(binding)
foo.run()
```

Foo.groovy:

```
someMethod(bar + '!')

def someMethod(baz) { // bar/baz value must be passed in
  // do something with baz
}
```

I have not tried this out, but it should be easy enough to plug it into Groovy Console and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have a named initializer, I used the `call` method, ending in `return this`:

```
def call(def env, String name) {
    this.env = env
    this.markDownName = "*${name}*"
    return this
}
```

then I can have the following idiomatic use of the constructor, with two sets of parantheses:

```
def helper = new Helper()(env, "front end verification")
```